# Open emacs in Dired mode

Tags: org-mode, init-file, dired, sorting, directory

I would like to open emacs in dired mode . files and folders should be organised in most recent file first order. Moreover I would like to highlight the Org files for easy selection. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you provide a directory on the command-line, it opens in dired mode.  For example

```
emacs .
```

...will open the current directory in dired mode.

The variable `dired-listing-switches' contains the switches sent to the ls command.  So adding

```
(setq dired-listing-switches "-lart")
```

to your startup config (or customizing it) should do what you want.

You can mark org files with `dired-mark-files-regexp` as follows:

```
emacs -Q . --eval '(dired-mark-files-regexp "\\.org$")' &
```